# I am unable to login to https://developer.salesforce.com/forums#!/feedtype=RECENT&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&

Tags: login-errors

After login, the page redirects back to the login page. How do I resolve this?

Sometimes the login happens but mostly it does not.

Comment: Have you tried to delete cookies? Temporary browser data? Open in incognito window? Back in the days I had plenty of such issues on SF sites,  but not recently.

Comment: I do not see any questions in the [queue](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=Developer_Forums&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS) after 4th so looks like other users are also facing the same issue. I am checking with my team and will update this thread as I have more inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for flagging this and apologies for the inconvenience.

Our team has fixed the issue. You should now be able to log in and post queries. The root cause has been identified as an internal configuration change. Our team would be working on making that change again but will be thoroughly testing and coordinating that change to avoid any downtime or login issues.